# imagem e hr lado-a-lado

Tags: html

Eu quero uma uma imagem (a curva amarela em baixo) e um hr dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E tenho o código assim:

```html
<div>
<img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/curva.png" alt="curva"/>
<hr style="height: 3px; width: 250px; border-width: 0; color: #d29e1d; position:absolute; background-color: #d29e1d; margin-bottom:10px;"/>
</div>
```

E eu não entendo porque é que isso acontece. Alguém sabe o porque?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode adicionar o `display: block` na imagem (já que logo após vem o `<hr>`) e também não vejo necessidade do `position: absolute`, algo como:

```css
.container img {
   display: block;
}

.container hr {
    width: 250px;
    height: 3px;
    border-width: 0;
    background-color: #d29e1d;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/curva.png" alt="curva"/>
   <hr/>
</div>
```

Ou com `border` (sem `<hr>`):

```css
.container img {
  display: block;
}

.container {
    width: 250px;
    border-bottom: 3px #d29e1d solid;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/curva.png" alt="curva"/>
</div>
```

Se quiser adicionar conteúdo ao lado direito da imagem você pode usar `background: ...;` combinado com `margin` ou `padding`:

```css
.container h1 {
   margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}
.container {
    width: 250px;
    border-bottom: 3px #d29e1d solid;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    background: url(
http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/curva.png) bottom left no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

Exemplo de texto a direita:

```css
.container h1 {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

.sub-container {
   float: left;
    width: 250px;
    border-bottom: 3px #d29e1d solid;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
.sub-container img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Texto</h1>
    <div class="sub-container">
        <img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/curva.png" alt="curva"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Recomendo estudar os princípios básicos do CSS (como `float` e `display`) recomendo o seguinte links:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started
3. http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/learning
4. http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/joe/cssjoe1.php (Maujor das CSS em Português :) )

Comment: Guilherme se eu quiser adicionar um <h1>SOBRE</h1> antes da imagem mas tudo na mesma linha? como faço? Já tentei com inline mas não resultou

Comment: lado direito da imagem

Comment: algo tipo isto http://gyazo.com/97f3af3cf2bb1082ddd5ea1c38ae54f6

Comment: @BrunoGibellino editado a resposta, adicionei alguns links para estudo

Answer (score 3):

Pra ficar lado a lado podes usar o `display:inline` e regular a altura com margin:

```
margin:29px 0 0;
display:inline;
```

Exemplo:

```css
.linha{
height: 3px; width: 250px; border-width: 0; color: #d29e1d; position:absolute; background-color: #d29e1d; margin:29px 0 0;
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div >
<img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/curva.png" alt="curva"/>
<hr class="linha"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma edição a resposta do @GuilhermeNascimento seria fazer da seguinte forma caso não possa colocar um `display:block`

```
.container img {
  float:left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container hr {
    position:relative;
    top:31px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 1px;
    border-width: 0;
    color: #d29e1d;
    background-color: #d29e1d;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

<div class="container">
    <img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/curva.png" alt="curva"/>
   <hr/>
</div>
```

Esta solução é menos elegante e mais engessada (pois tem de saber o `height` da imagem) porem tem o mesmo resultado.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9m9PV/64/)