# Imagem com hr horizontal centrado verticalmente ao meio

Tags: html, css

Boas,

Eu tenho aqui um problema que em meter um `<h1>` seguido de uma imagem e de um `<hr>` como na seguinte [imagem](http://gyazo.com/351093fd77975ad28a2ce06c8379290b).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o seguinte código:

```html
<div id="bola"><h4 style="text-align: left; display:block">Bibliotecas</h4>
<div id="bola2">
      <img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/circun.png" alt="curva" style="float:left; display:inline-block"/>
      <hr style="height:3px;width:100px;border-width:0;color:#D29E1D;background-color:#D29E1D;float:left">
</div>
</div>
```

E eu não consigo pôr isso como deve de ser. Alguém sabe porque?

Comment: O último exemplo da [resposta à sua pergunta anterior](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69825/74) parece resolver isso, não?

Comment: @BrunoGilbellino Veja minha resposta. Não existe a necessidade de utilizar imagem para fazer este ícone.

Comment: Mas e se ele quiser colocar uma imagem diferente ali futuramente? Acho que você deveria dar uma segunda opção de código. Seria útil para muitos no futuro. @MoisesGama

Comment: @Florida Editei  e está feito. Veja.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iae eu só faria com `CSS`, sem utilizar imagens e usando `absolute`.

Execute e veja o resultado. Claro você pode mudar como desejar.

Segue o ***Scritp***:

```css
div.baseLogo {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
h4.textoLogo {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: block;
}
div.bolaCss {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #D29E1D;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 130px;
}
div.linhaDireita {
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 3px solid #D29E1D;
  top: 16px;
  left: 153px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="baseLogo">
  <h4 class="textoLogo">Bibliotecas</h4>
  <div class="bolaCss"></div>
  <div class="linhaDireita"></div>
</div>
```

**VERSÃO COM UTILIZAÇÃO DE IMAGEM**

```css
div.baseLogo {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
h4.textoLogo {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: block;
}
div.bolaImagem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 130px;
}
div.linhaDireita {
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 3px solid #D29E1D;
  top: 16px;
  left: 153px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="baseLogo">
  <h4 class="textoLogo">Bibliotecas</h4>
  <div class="bolaImagem">
    <img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/circun.png" alt="curva">
  </div>
  <div class="linhaDireita"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito arriscado fazer assim.

Comment: @DiegoSouza Porque?

Comment: Eu sei que o AP está usando *css inline* na pergunta, mas acho que facilitaria muito o entendimento se você separasse o html do css, *btw* +1.

Comment: @re22 vou montar assim, e já atualizo.

Comment: @re22 Feito, veja.

Answer (score 2):

Boas,

Em primeiro lugar tens que ter cuidado com o fechar das tags.

Uma das maneiras que tens para alinhares elementos é usando o `float`

```
<div id="bola"><h4 style="text-align: left; display:block">Bibliotecas</h4></div>
<div id="bola2">
      <img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/circun.png" alt="curva" style="float:left; display:inline-block"/>
      <hr style="height:3px;width:100px;border-width:0;color:#D29E1D;background-color:#D29E1D;float:left"></hr>
</div>
```

Aqui só te fechei as tags que não estavam fechadas

Acrescentei este **CSS**

```
#bola{
   float: left;
}

#bola2 {
     float: left;
     margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Tens aqui o [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xwb83rLm/) onde podes testar

**P.S.** Utilizei o `margin-top` para centrar mais ou menos a `#bola2` em relação à `#bola`

**ALTERNATIVA**

Caso não pretendas usar um ficheiro **CSS** para guardar os estilos, podes sempre adicionar ao próprio **HTML**

```
  <div id="bola"style="float: left">
        <h4 style="text-align: left; display:block">Bibliotecas</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="bola2" style="float: left;margin-top: 20px;">
      <img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/circun.png" alt="curva" style="float:left; display:inline-block"/>
    <hr style="height:3px;width:100px;border-width:0;color:#D29E1D;background-color:#D29E1D;float:left"></hr>
</div>
```

Tens aqui o [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xwb83rLm/1/) deste caso

Comment: @Florida Tem a certeza?

Comment: @Florida o do autor esta: http://prntscr.com/7ihurf e o exemplo que fiz está http://prntscr.com/7ihv41

Comment: Acho que equivoquei, não entendi muito bem a pergunta, vou remover o post e deixar que o autor se pronuncie.

Answer (score 1):

Eu tirei seu CSS inline do HTML. Nunca mais faça isso a não ser que seja assinatura de e-mail. Enfim, não vem ao caso.

Nos elementos abaixo distribuí por meio de `display:inline-block` e usei a propriedade `line-height` com `vertical-align:middle` deixando assim a imagem centralizada na DIV e também o HR.

```css
#bola {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
#bola2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 70%;
  line-height: 60px;
}
#bola2 img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
hr {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: -7px;
  background-color: #D19D1C;
  height: 3px;
  border: none;
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="bola" class="alinhar">
  <h4>Bibliotecas</h4>
</div>
<div id="bola2" class="alinhar">
  <img src="http://culturalis.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/circun.png" alt="curva" />
  <hr></hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Podia colocar esse código parar rodar em um *snippet*, mas tudo bem, +1.

Comment: Quem negativou deveria no mínimo justificar, pelo menos das respostas até o momento essa me pareceu a mais elegante.